# Is there a way to access IE Developer Tools in IE Tab on Firefox?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox-addon, ie-developer-tools

When I'm using IE Tab on Firefox, I can't use stuff like Firebug or Web Developer because I'm technically using IE. I tried using the F12, the IE keyboard shortcut for Developer Tools, but that doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how to access the IE developer tools on IE Tab/Firefox, or at least get some kind of Javascript debugger working on IE Tab?

Comment: How about simply opening Internet Explorer?

Comment: I'm pretty certain that there is none. IE Tab doesn't embed Internet Explorer (meaning the browser UI which includes the Developer Tools), it only embeds its rendering engine.